# Shall I explain to grad school admissions that 'the first year didn't count' (UK)?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, united-kingdom, transcript-of-records

I am considering applying for US PhD Program. In the UK, at many unis the first year does not count towards degree classification. Is this known in the US? Will they be wondering why I stated I have X %, but they calculate Y % ? Shall I explain to grad school admissions that 'the first year didn't count' towards my degree classification?

Comment: This needs more explanation. Why didn't it count? Is it a special case? Is it a regional thing that schools you are applying to may not know about?

Comment: The schools you're applying to may decide that your first year "counts", even though the school at which you spent that year does not.

Answer (score 5):

For the benefit of non UK members, the first year marks of a degree at a UK university is not used for calculating a student's final grade. The only requirement to continue on the degree is achieve at least 40%. It is therefore not uncommon for students to achieve marks in their first year which do not reflect their full abilities, and while it does not affect their grades it can affect how future employer or post graduate admissions view their application!

If this is the case you should address this in your personal statement. Tell them how you gained a new perspective and work ethic after your first year at university and demonstrate this with your improved results in your subsequent years along with appropriate participation in university clubs and societies.

If however your first year marks are consistent with your subsequent years, there is no need to mention it. Your application is about you as a potential student, not about explaining the intricacies of UK grade calculations.

**Edit:** The reasoning behind only requiring a mark of 40% for the first year is to allow students some adjustment to a more independent study style and also to give young adults entering university the freedom to have new life experiences outside of academia. The prevalent philosophy at UK institutions is that academic achievement is not the only goal of attending university (though it is obviously still important!)

Since the progression of students enrolled on a degree is decided on a department by department basis its impossible to find a single decree stating this how all UK universities operate it is by far how the majority work. Provided below are links to progression guidance from 2 UK universities, stating that only pass marks (40%) are required and that this mark will not be used to calculate degree classifications.
[University of York Progression](https://www.york.ac.uk/media/staffhome/learningandteaching/documents/Student_guide_to_rules_for_progression_and_awards_in_ug_programmes.pdf), [University of Durham Progression](https://www.dur.ac.uk/natural.sciences/faq/year1marks/)

Comment: Would you please provide more info (or link) about _the first year marks of a degree at a UK university is not used for calculating a student's final grade_? Thanks.

Comment: Thank for the explanation. As you said, "_impossible to find a single decree stating this how all UK universities operate it is by far how the majority work_", obviously the OP needs to explain to us what he is asking and also he needs to explain to the school he is applying to since  not necessarily **all** UK universities operate the same way.

Comment: This is not true at all UK universities, e.g. the first year counts at Imperial College

Comment: Interesting, thanks for explanation. It reminds me of the MIT system where you can take courses as Pass/No Record, but here you have a record... but it doesn't really matter? I think in this case it should for sure should be mentioned in the personal statement, but people in the US would only buy it if it's clear your low grades were due to experimenting (i.e. many extra/hard courses or a side job). If it's because you knew that those grades didn't matter so you just partied around, no one will care if you say "but those didn't matter".

Answer (score 3):

I've served on a PhD admissions committee as a student member, and we considered many different kinds of extenuating factors that might explain low GPA. That committee would certainly have appreciated the info. I would mention it, being careful to frame it in a way that portrays myself as a successful future researcher.

The concern of a PhD admissions committee is primarily, "Will this individual successfully complete our program?" and secondary, "Will they be a leader in their field of research after completing our program?" What you do *not* want to do is imply that you blew off the entire year because you didn't have grades to motivate you. No grad school wants someone who's primarily motivated by grades. Even if your PhD program puts emphasis on grades in the program (mine doesn't, but I think the more STEM fields might), you won't have grades to motivate you after you complete the degree.

So mention it, but tell a valid story--something like:

> "I've always been more concerned about learning than grades, although grades are important. In the UK they do _____, and this was ideal for me because I could get settled and embrace all the learning opportunities of my university without having to worry too much about a summative assessment. [Give an example of something valuable you learned that first year.] So I can understand your need to look at grades, but I'd point out that grades weren't my primary concern my first year because of the UK system, and that my GPA after that point was _____.

I don't think this feature of UK higher ed is well known in the US.

Comment: thanks a lot. do you think it is even worth mentioning if my grades aren't too bad? I asked my supervisor about it, because I had some health issues etc. and she said to just not mention anything.

Comment: @Chris Doyle Depends on how not-bad is "not too bad." If you feel like you otherwise have a strong application and it shouldn't be an issue, then I wouldn't worry about it. You can always mention it in passing in the phone interview (if you have one). I don't think it's a problem to mention it if you want to.